# Finding the value of a sum over all the subsets of a given set

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Given a sequence $A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_n\}$ we have to find the

```
Summation of Length*(All the subsequence product)
For EX:
A= {1 2}
There are 3 sub sequences = {1} , {2} , {1,2}
S = 1*(1) + 1*(2) + 2*(1*2)
  = 1+2+4= 7
```

Similarly for  $A =\{1,2,3\}$ we have $S= 46$.

Is there an efficient way to compute this quantity, as each element will appear $2^{n-1}$ times ?

Comment: Please fix your question title.  You are not taking a product over all subsequences, you are taking a sum.

Comment: Could you clarify the second part of your question? You want to compute $S$ when which elements appear how many times?

Comment: This one comes from the blackrock competition from Hackerrank which is still ongoing

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are the roots of the polynomial
$$ p(t) = (t-a_1)(t-a_2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(t-a_n) = t^n-e_1 t^{n-1}+e_2 t^{n-1}+\ldots.\tag{1} $$
It follows that:
$$ r(t)=(1+ta_1)(1+ta_2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(1+t a_n) = 1+e_1 t+e_2 t^2+\ldots + e_n t^n \tag{2}$$
where $e_k$ is an [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in $a_1,\ldots,a_n$.
We want to evaluate:

> $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} k\,e_k = \left.\frac{d}{dt}r(t)\,\right|_{t=1}=\color{red}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{a_k+1}\right)\cdot\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+a_k)}.\tag{3} $$

The last identity follows from:
$$ f'(x) = f(x)\cdot\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x) \tag{3}$$
and:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\log r(t) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{d}{dt}\log(1+a_k t).\tag{4}$$

Comment: This one comes from the blackrock competition from Hackerrank which is still ongoing